# Array of runtime size and frame size deduction

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int size;
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int foo[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            scanf("%d", &foo[i]);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            printf("%d\n",foo[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

How does this code compile? More specifically: how does the compiler know what is the size of frame `main` if size of local variable `foo`is not known at compile time. I was expecting a compile error along the lines: "`foo` has incomplete type"

To have also [tried](https://ideone.com/ivkqAa) the code and it also runs fine:

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082126/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-c99-vla-compared-to-malloc-free

Comment: You could examine the assembly generated by your favourite compiler

Comment: "how does the compiler know what is the size of frame main" --> The compiler does not know the size of `int foo[size]` at compile time, nor does it need to know at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you will first read data to specify size of array elements and then it will allocate that array on stack.

This approach is available from C99.

How compiler knows the size? It doesn't know. if you will enter too big value for `size` you may get stack overflow.

It will compile in a way that it will make sure to create as big push as required to put entire array to stack according to variable of size multiplied by size of single array element:

```
stack_size_usage = size * sizeof (int)
```

In C89, this would reproduce error as all variables must be first initialized before any code can be executed.

---

I would instead use HEAP memory for this type of allocation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int size;
    int* foo;
    scanf("%d", &size);

    foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo) * size);
    if (!foo) { /* failed, stop program */ }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &foo[i]);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d\n",foo[i]);

    free(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that during a function call the stack pointer is incremented twice? First time for the local variable size, and the second time incremented with `sizeof(foo[size])`?

Comment: Yes, it is in fact. Please check my second example. It is better to use it.