# Most portable ways of allocating memory and reading arrays with fread() in C

Tags: c, malloc, fread, calloc

Just wondering what is the soundest way to allocate memory and `fread()` array data from a file in C.

First, an explanation:

```
int32_t longBuffer;
```

Now, when freading in the longBuffer, the code could go as:

```
fread(&longBuffer, sizeof(longBuffer), 1, fd); //version 1
fread(&longBuffer, sizeof(int32_t), 1, fd); //version 2
```

Among the two, I would say that version 1 is more bug-safe, since if the type of `longBuffer` changes (let's say to `int16_t`), one does not have to worry about forgetting to update the `fread()`'s `sizeof()` with the new type.

Now, for an array of data, the code could be written as:

```
//listing 1
int8_t *charpBuffer=NULL; //line 1
charpBuffer = calloc(len, sizeof(int8_t)); //line 2
fread(charpBuffer, sizeof(int8_t), len, fd); //line 3
```

However, this exhibits the problem exposed in the first example: one has to worry about not forgetting to synchronize the `sizeof(<type>)` instructions when changing the type of `charpBuffer` (let's say, from `int8_t*` to `int16_t*`).

So, one may attempt to write:

```
fread(charpBuffer, sizeof(charpBuffer[0]), len, fd); //line 3a
```

as a more bug-safe version. This should work since, after the allocation on line 2, writing `charpBuffer[0]` is perfectly valid.

Also, one could write:

```
fread(charpBuffer, sizeof(*charpBuffer), len, fd); //line 3b
```

However, trying to do the same for memory allocation, such as:

```
charpBuffer = calloc(len, sizeof(charpBuffer[0])); //line 2a
```

while better in syntax, exhibits undefined behaviour because, at this stage, writing `charpBuffer[0]` results into dereferencing a NULL pointer. Also, writing:

```
charpBuffer = calloc(len, sizeof(*charpBuffer)); //line 2b
```

exhibits the same problem.

So, now the questions:

1. Are the lines of code "line 2b" and "line 3b" correct (ignore the undefined behaviour for this question) or there are some tricks that I miss w.r.t. their "wiser" counterparts such as "line 2a/3a" and "line 2/3"?
2. What would be the most bug-safe way to write the "listing 1" code, but avoiding any form of undefined behaviour?

EDITS (in order to clarify some aspects):

The discussion took wrong direction. The question of compile time vs run time is one thing (and I would like to have a standard guarantee for this one, too, but it is not the topic). And the question of undefined behaviour for sizeof(NULL dereferencing) is another. Even if at compile time, I am not convinced that this is guaranteed by the standard to not result in UB. Does the standard provide any guarantees?

Comment: "-prone" doesn't mean what you think it does. "Bug-prone" (or "error-prone") means the opposite of how you're using it.

Comment: @user4815162342: sorry, English is not my native. I will correct.

Comment: I understand as English is not my native language either. It later occurred to me that "bug-proof" is a similar-sounding word that conveys the intended meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From C99 6.5.4.3.2 (emphasis mine):

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
>   determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer.
>   **If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the
>   operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the
>   result is an integer constant.**

That the operand is "not evaluated" means that it's perfectly safe to access `sizeof(charBuffer[0])` or `sizeof(*charBuffer)`, because those expressions are only used for their types. Example 3 on the same page goes on to explicitly document the `sizeof array / sizeof array[0]` idiom for computing the number of elements in an array without any mention or implication that it wouldn't be valid for empty arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this clears the issue for now, and gives an acceptable reference to the standard. I will accept this.

Comment: Remember that C does not acknowledge the existence of 'empty arrays'; arrays of zero length are not permitted by the standard.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a wrong idea about the `sizeof` operator. This operator is evaluated at compile-time, so the expressions that you pass to it have no chance of being evaluated while the program is running.

In the context of a `sizeof` operator, `*charBuffer` and `charBuffer[0]` are both safe regardless of whether they are used before or after the corresponding memory is available. It is just a way of avoiding to type the name of the type, less duplication therefore.

**EDIT**

As commented below, there is a notable exception to the rule that `sizeof` is evaluated at compile-time (although it is not relevant to the code posted in the question). Since C and C++ allow variable-length arrays as automatic variables, applying `sizeof` on these may actually involve some runtime overhead.

Regarding your fears about undefined behaviour, I don't think there is a ground for that since:

```
int vla[n]; // declare a variable-length array of length n

/* The compiler will produce code using the value of n prior to
   declaring the array to compute its size. */
x = sizeof(vla);

/* The space for the array is already available, so the expression 
   *vla is not UB anywhere (except if n is 0). Furthermore, n is 
   not involved in the computation and the operator can be evaluated at 
   compile-time. */
y = sizeof(*vla);

z = sizeof(vla[0]); // same thing
```

Comment: sizeof isn't evaluated at compile-time for all scenarios.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2035292/541686

Comment: Are you sure about those? I know that GCC works (mostly) this way, however, I am not sure that the standard guarantees that behaviour.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: This example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2709634/1284631 compiles under gcc on my machine and it works as expected (the sizeof operator prints the length of the array, which is known only at runtime).

Comment: @axeoth: Since VLA's are always automatic variables, their space is already reserved at the time of their declaration. So it is safe to use these expressions in conjunction with a `sizeof` operator and a VLA.

Comment: I understand you point of view. However, I want to know *how much safe* it is. I know that works in 99% of the cases. But I want to know if it works in 100%. And that guarantee is provided only by the standard. If it is there, it is OK for me. Compilers may adhere to the "as expected" practice, but as long as it is not in the standard, it is not good enough for me. I am chased by the standard enforcer.

Comment: @axeoth: I cannot quote the standard, but Wikipedia says essentially the same thing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Implementation: *In most cases, sizeof is a compile-time operator, which means that during compilation sizeof expressions get replaced by constant result-values. However, sizeof applied to a variable length array, introduced in C99, requires computation during program execution.*

Comment: The discussion took wrong direction. The question of compiletime/runtime is one thing (and I would like to have a standard guarantee for this one, too, but it is not the topic). And the question of undefined behavior for sizeof(NULL dereferencing) is another. Even if at compile time, I am not convinced that this is guaranteed by the standard to not result in UB.